# Como calcular a próxima casa disponível?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

De momento estou a realizar um projeto e estou com um problema com um algoritmo.
Tendo em conta as 4 direções ( Norte,Leste,Sul,Oeste), se o utilizador escolher um dos 4, deve ser alocado a próxima casa disponível com 1 casa vazia de distância.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A casa com coordenadas ( 0,0 ) não pode ser ocupada.
Se ainda ninguém tiver criado conta a primeira pessoa a escolher uma das direcções fica com a primeira casa, por exemplo Selecciona Norte fica com o N1, Selecciona Sul fica com o S1.
A segunda pessoa a escolher Norte ficaria com o quadrado com X a esquerda do N1.

Como poderia fazer para devolver a próxima coordenada disponível dando como argumento a direção ?

Comment: Ainda ninguém soube resolver?

Comment: melhor você especificar com o que você quer criar isso, porque tem tag de PHP, Javascrip, Mysql, Sql,....